# List the directories and move those to another location (RHEL_8)

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a situation where we have log directories of each day, We want to first identify those which are older than 30 days and move those directories to another location.
Here we can’t use find with mv command because of Linux Admin policy.

I've tried to do this with command

```
ls -1t | head -5 | xargs -i mv {} another_dir/
```

Comment: What you did so far?

Comment: I used this command ls -1t | head -5 | xargs -i mv {} another_dir/

Comment: Instead of answering in a comment, it's a better practice to [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767498/edit) your question instead so all the relevant details are available without browsing through comments. I added the command now for you. It'd also be good to add the results of what you've tried. In a failure situation knowing _how_ exactly something fails helps in finding the solution.

Comment: What will happen if you have more than 5 directories which are >30 days old? What about white space in directory names? What is the format of directories? Which time you will use for reference of 30 days old?